# How to check if a list is email enabled or not?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, central-administration, wss-3.0, email-enabled-library

I am preparing the inventory for one migration project I am working on. For this I need to get all the email enabled lists. I know it is possible using powershell [get Email enabled List](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/457387e3-05af-425c-9de4-5aa15d673a19/getting-a-list-of-all-email-enabled-document-libraries-witin-a-sharepoint-2007-web-app?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) but unfortunately I dont have access to run power shell commands in client's environment.

Is there any way through front end / client side code to check these. ? I appreciate through front end but any help is admired.

**PS:** I am working on WSS 3.0 and SharePoint 2013..... 
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it in Javascript/JQuery with SPServices. Maybe you can use these ideas in another language. Call `getAllEmails` once per site collection with the site collection URL. I used this to see how many we used, since SharePoint online doesn't allow them. One of our sticking points of migrating to online.

```
function getAllEmails(url) {
        siteList = "<table><tr style='background-color: #78FF78'><td class='fmgTD'><b>Site</b></td><td class='fmgTD'><b>List</b></td><td class='fmgTD'><b>Email Address</b></td></tr>";
    getSiteLists(url, "Home");
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetWebCollection",
        webURL: url,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {
            //      alert(xData.responseText);
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").each(function() {
                getSiteLists($(this).attr("Url"),$(this).attr("Title"));
                url = $(this).attr("Url");
                getSubSites(url);

            });
        }
    });
    siteList += "</table>";
    $('#emailSites').append(siteList);

}
function getSiteLists(weburl ,webtitle) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListCollection",
        webURL: weburl,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {
            var count = 0;
            $(xData.responseXML).find("List").each(function() {
                if($(this).attr("EmailAlias") && $(this).attr("EmailAlias").substr(0,13) != 'recordscenter'){
                    if(count == 0) {
                    siteList += "<tr><td class='fmgTD'>" + webtitle + "</td>";
                    } else {
                    siteList += "<tr><td class='fmgTD'>&nbsp;</td>";
                    }
                    count++;
                    siteList += "<td class='fmgTD'>" + $(this).attr("Title") + "</td><td class='fmgTD'><b>" +$(this).attr("EmailAlias") + "</b>@THEEMAILADDRESS</td></tr>";
                }
            }); 
        }               

    });
}
function getSubSites(weburl) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetWebCollection",
        webURL: weburl,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {
            //      alert(xData.responseText);
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").each(function() {
                // now get all ists for this web
                getSiteLists($(this).attr("Url"),$(this).attr("Title") );
                getSubSites($(this).attr("Url"));

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well this looks fine for me. $(this).attr("EmailAlias") will give me email id of a person OR a group of people? I mean what this alias refers to?

Comment: The email alias attribute is the email address - the part before the @. So if your incoming emails end in @yoursharepoint.com, for example, and you set up a list/library with an incoming email of accounting@yoursharepoint.com, the EmailAlias will be 'accounting'. Mine skips over all the recordscenter email addresses that were created - at least they were when we moved to SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Email setting is not possible for all types of lists. Below are the lists where this setting is possible.

**Document**, **picture**, **form library**, **Announcements list**, **Calendar list**, **Discussion board**, **Blog**.

You can check this under list setting >> Communications.

Comment: Thank you for the response but my Question is completely different. It says how can check that a certain List say Library A is email enabled or not? it will be better if I get the list of all email enabled lists under a site collection!

Comment: Here LIST means any type of list; be it a Document, picture, form library, Announcements list, Calendar list, Discussion board, Blog or anything

Comment: There is no option to get all the list of email enabled list/libraries. 

You will have to use PowerShell and you need to get admin permissions to run that PowerShell.